# Flutter SDK IOs Privacy

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using the agora.io Flutter (agora_rtc_engine: 1.0.5) for a cross-platform application. In the info.plist the io.flutter.embedded_views_preview is set to Yes as the documentation specifies.

My test application currently has only a main screen and the example Agora flutter video sharing example provided on Github in the quick start https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart.

When I packaged the app and submitted it to the Apple App Store it is rejected because of the privacy permissions. The rejection states that the following privacy notices are not set:

- NSContactsUsageDescription
- NSCalendarsUsageDescription
- NSAppleMusicUsageDescription
- NSMotionUsageDescription
- NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription
- Missing Push Notification Entitlement
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

There is no code in the flutter application that touches any of these areas.

Is this a result of setting the io.flutter.embedded_views_preview to be true?

Is this expected or is there something that I am missing that is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you're adding user permissions for stuff that your app might not need.

This is something that you can do to prevent this:

- Don't hardcode any permission in the plist/manifest
- And to not have asserts in the package that make the compiler fail when you don't have the permissions for a feature you aren't even using.
- If you're using permission_handler plugin as used in Agora's quickstart guide then you will have to probably mention all the permissions that you wont be using in your Podfile. You can refer the below link on how to do that:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21941#issuecomment-576121308

Comment: Thanks, the issue was I am using the permissions_handler and failed to realize that you have to specify what you are NOT using.